# Submitting Vue Form with Axios and PHPMailer

Tags: php, vue.js, phpmailer, axios

I'm struggling a little with this.

I'm trying to submit my Vue Form data using Axios and sending myself an email using PHPMailer.

This is what I have for the Vue part:

```
<script>
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            step: 1,
            counter: 0,
            debt: {
                name: null,
                email: null,
                tel: null
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        prev() {
            this.step--;
        },
        next() {
            this.step++;
        },
        hasClicked(value) {
            alert(this.counter);
        },
        submit() {
            axios.post('post.php', {
                'name': this.debt.name,
                'email': this.debt.email
            }).then(response => {
                console.log('success', response.data.message)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response)
            });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

This is my post.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../../../vendor/autoload.php';

header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

$name = $input['name'];
$email = $input['email'];
$tel = $input['tel'];

$result['message'] = '';
$result['error']  = false;

if($name){
$result['message']  = $name $email $tel;
$result['error']  = false;
}


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);  

foreach($environment['phpmailer'] as $key => $value) {
      $mail->$key = $value;
}

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom(constant('SITE_EMAIL'),constant('SITE_TITLE'));
$mail->addAddress($environment['mail_recipients']);

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Title';
$mail->Body    = $result;
$mail->send();

echo json_encode($result);
```

If I remove the phpmailer part from post.php it does send through the content from the form. But I cannot get it to send the data to an email.

Hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks, Jake.

Comment: What's the error? If you're receiving the data with Php, then the Vue part of the question is irrelevant!?

Comment: You might get more of a clue if you actually do some error checking, as all the PHPMailer examples do, and look in your web server's error log.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yes, your right, I'm sorry, the Vue forms submits the data, my issue is once the Vue Form has been submitted and the data passed through how do I trigger PHPMailer to send the Vue data to an email.

Comment: Hi did you take a look at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example ? It looks like you did not set up your host credentials. Also i just wanted to thank you, because your `file_get_contents` helped me with my problem :D <3

Comment: @moesphemie Hey man yes I sorted all of this now thanks and it works perfectly :). Also great that the `file_get_contents` sorted you out, happy all round :)

Comment: how did you solve this @Henshall